# Elasticsearch uses 100% CPU when doing nothing

Tags: linux, elasticsearch

When I run `top`, I consistently see elasticsearch using around 100% CPU. I've completely disconnected logstash, and the output of checking "curl localhost:9200/_nodes/hot_threads" only shows threads idling:

`ubuntu@ip-10-43-108-54:/data$ curl localhost:9200/_nodes/hot_threads
::: {7uyKrAF}{7uyKrAFGS0yMk0XiIrEzUQ}{Bk4GTlkiSqOgNU1cEJVxKw}{10.43.108.54}{10.43.108.54:9300}{ml.machine_memory=16825712640, xpack.installed=true, ml.max_open_jobs=20, ml.enabled=true}
   Hot threads at 2018-10-25T18:46:33.827Z, interval=500ms, busiestThreads=3, ignoreIdleThreads=true:`

ubuntu@ip-10-43-108-54:/data$ curl localhost:9200/_nodes/hot_threads
::: {7uyKrAF}{7uyKrAFGS0yMk0XiIrEzUQ}{Bk4GTlkiSqOgNU1cEJVxKw}{10.43.108.54}{10.43.108.54:9300}{ml.machine_memory=16825712640, xpack.installed=true, ml.max_open_jobs=20, ml.enabled=true}
   Hot threads at 2018-10-25T18:46:35.452Z, interval=500ms, busiestThreads=3, ignoreIdleThreads=true:

```
0.0% (101.7micros out of 500ms) cpu usage by thread 'elasticsearch[7uyKrAF][[timer]]'
 10/10 snapshots sharing following 2 elements
   java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
   org.elasticsearch.threadpool.ThreadPool$CachedTimeThread.run(ThreadPool.java:543)
```

ubuntu@ip-10-43-108-54:/data$ curl localhost:9200/_nodes/hot_threads
::: {7uyKrAF}{7uyKrAFGS0yMk0XiIrEzUQ}{Bk4GTlkiSqOgNU1cEJVxKw}{10.43.108.54}{10.43.108.54:9300}{ml.machine_memory=16825712640, xpack.installed=true, ml.max_open_jobs=20, ml.enabled=true}
   Hot threads at 2018-10-25T18:46:38.779Z, interval=500ms, busiestThreads=3, ignoreIdleThreads=true:

ubuntu@ip-10-43-108-54:/data$ curl localhost:9200/_nodes/hot_threads
::: {7uyKrAF}{7uyKrAFGS0yMk0XiIrEzUQ}{Bk4GTlkiSqOgNU1cEJVxKw}{10.43.108.54}{10.43.108.54:9300}{ml.machine_memory=16825712640, xpack.installed=true, ml.max_open_jobs=20, ml.enabled=true}
   Hot threads at 2018-10-25T18:46:40.579Z, interval=500ms, busiestThreads=3, ignoreIdleThreads=true:

```
0.0% (90.5micros out of 500ms) cpu usage by thread 'elasticsearch[7uyKrAF][[timer]]'
 10/10 snapshots sharing following 2 elements
   java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
   org.elasticsearch.threadpool.ThreadPool$CachedTimeThread.run(ThreadPool.java:543)

0.0% (33.8micros out of 500ms) cpu usage by thread 'ticker-schedule-trigger-engine'
 10/10 snapshots sharing following 2 elements
   java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
   org.elasticsearch.xpack.watcher.trigger.schedule.engine.TickerScheduleTriggerEngine$Ticker.run(TickerScheduleTriggerEngine.java:161)</code>
```

What are the typical causes for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The threads being shown as Hot are the ones that Elastic considers hot.   To diagnose your condition you will want to see all the threads in the process to see if there is activity that is unexpected.  To gather this information follow these commands:

`ps aux | grep elastic`

> hogstrom          **4675**   0.0  3.8  7018056 1284496 s001  S+    4:43PM 
>   0:17.49
>   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
>   -Xms1g -Xmx1g [snip ...]

Then grab the PID and issue the following command to get a dump of all threads in the JVM.    Using the example above,

`jcmd 4675 Thread.print`

This will give you a thread dump of all Java threads.  There you can see what threads are in the JVM and their state.

> "elasticsearch[cXcMg1Z][http_server_worker][T#2]" #61 daemon prio=5
>   os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fa84fbdd000 nid=0x14a03 **runnable**
>   [0x00007000147fa000]    java.lang.Thread.State: **RUNNABLE**  at
>   sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.kevent0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.poll(KQueueArrayWrapper.java:198)   at
>   sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl.doSelect(KQueueSelectorImpl.java:117)
>     at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)

The example thread is Runnable.  Going through the all the threads you should find a Thread that is running and will point out the task that is consuming CPU.

Comment: The only runnable thread that wasn't running "epollwait" was a logger for ml in the xpack, which I don't use. The elasticsearch.log is showing a lot of garbage collection activity occurring though, lots of lines like `[WARN ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [7uyKrAF] [gc][7673] overhead, spent [2.3s] collecting in the last [2.7s]`

Comment: It appears to be a periodic spike to 300+% that will then dwindle down.

Comment: Can you increase your heap size .... if your in GC then you don't have enough memory.   Are you running with -verbose:gc.  That should give you an idea of how much memory you are using and the relationship to used versus available memory.

Comment: I changed the heap size from 1GB to 10GB, and it's still chugging CPU cycles, but it's a lot stabler and more responsive, thanks!